# Recursive file structure got by RecursiveDirecrtoryIterator

Tags: php, recursion, iterator, filesystems

I am trying to get a full file structure using the RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator and RegexIterator using the below code to get all the .php files in the system:

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(realpath("/"));
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
$regex = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\.php$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
```

But when I var_dump $regex, I get this:

> object(RegexIterator)[4431]
>    public 'replacement' => null

What am I doing wrong here? It has me stumped...

**NOTE**
I got this code from: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#97228)

Comment: @unixarmy, I wouldn't say this is a duplicate of that as the OP of that question is getting a runtime error where I am not, I am getting it through, just not the information

Comment: Yes, $regex is an "Iterator"; you need to iterate over it (using `foreach($regex as $file)` for example) to get the individual values

Comment: @MarkBaker, I did that just and it worked perfectly, stupid mistake on my part, would you mind putting it as an answer so I can mark as correct as soon as I can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$regex` is an "Iterator",  you need to iterate over it (using foreach($regex as $file) for example) to get the individual values.

You need to iterate/loop over that object - in the same way that you'd iterate over a database resultset - to get the individual values:

```
foreach($regex as $file) {
    var_dump($file);
}
```

Note that `$file` is an array in this case, with a string value (the full filepath) as the only entry